# Fluent API с ветвлениями

Tags: c#, .net, архитектура

Хочется сделать для одной задачи, что-то такое, как сделано в `Entity Framework`, когда пишешь `Include`, а после него `ThenInclude` и можешь работать с объектом, который выбрал на прошлом шаге, а затем если написать Include, то снова возвращаешься к исходному объекту.

Хочу по итогу получить набор целых цепочек к свойствам от первого свойства и до последнего, который указал пользователь в цепочке.

Однако, не понимаю, как это все реализовывается.
Скажем, как будет выглядеть иерархия и кто должен отвечать за агрегацию цепочек или нужно вообще организовывать двусвязных список...?

Надеюсь, я правильно объяснил.

Comment: В чем вопрос то? Вы не знаете как делать `FluentBuilder` или вы не знаете как его делать для вашей конкретной задачи? Если для задачи, то потрудитесь её хотя бы описать.

Comment: Не знаю,как сделать FluentBuilder =(

Answer (score 5):

Сделать простенький FluentBuilder - дело нехитрое. Можно использовать интерфейсы, чтобы ограничивать отдельные операции. Вот пример

```
public class FluentBuilder : 
         FluentBuilder.IStageOne, FluentBuilder.IStageTwo, FluentBuilder.IStageFinal
{
```

Приватный конструктор, чтобы не было возможности создать экземпляр строителя ане класса. Элемент не обязательный, но часто встречается.

```
    private FluentBuilder() {
        _internalState = new StringBuilder();
        _internalState.AppendLine("Start");
    }
```

Внутреннее состояние класса

```
    private StringBuilder _internalState = new StringBuilder();
```

Создание первого шага

```
    public static IStageOne Create(){
        return new FluentBuilder();
    }
```

Операция вернет второй шаг

```
    public IStageTwo OperationOne(string arg)
    {
        _internalState.AppendLine($"OperationOne with {arg}");
        return this;
    }
```

Возврат финального шага

```
    public IStageFinal OperationTwo(string arg)
    {
        _internalState.AppendLine($"OperationTwo with {arg}");
        return this; 
    }
```

Создание объекта из внутреннего состояния

```
    public string Build()
    {
        _internalState.AppendLine("End");
        return _internalState.ToString();
    }
```

Мы не планируем иметь реализацию интерфейсов за пределами класса, потому держим их внутри класса.

```
    public interface IStageOne
    {
        IStageTwo OperationOne(string arg);
    }

    public interface IStageTwo
    {
        IStageFinal OperationTwo(string arg);
    }

    public interface IStageFinal
    {
        String Build();
    }
}
```

Пример использования

```
var result = FluentBuilder.Create()
    .OperationOne("one")
    .OperationTwo("two")
    .Build();
    
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Вывод

```
Start
OperationOne with one
OperationTwo with two
End
```