# Невидимые входные параметры

Tags: c#, атрибуты, передача-параметров

Есть метод с параметрами по умолчанию. Требуется разделить способы вызова метода, а именно - если вызывается в родной сборке, возможность изменения параметров остается, если во внешней сборке, вызывается без изменения параметров по умолчанию.

Перегрузками невозможно, поясню:

```
static void Foo([CallerMemberName] string methodname = null)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(methodname);
   }
```

Вызов метода:

```
Foo();      // вызов возможен в любой сборке 
Foo("Bar"); // вызов возможен только в родной сборке
```

Иными словами нужен запрет на инициализацию параметров по умолчанию во внешней сборке, в идеале они должны быть просто невидимы.

Что не получилось: разные оболочки для метода, в этом cлучае methodname - имя оболочки, а не реально вызывающего метода. Что ожидаемо не получится - оценка изменений параметров по умолчанию, они изменяются всегда - либо задаются в вызове, либо изменяются вследствие атрибута. И отследить, кто их изменил и выбросить исключение вряд ли возможно.

Добавить in или out тоже вряд ли - параметр, скорее всего, может быть и в том, и в другом статусе.

Есть варианты, идеи?

Спасибо.

UPD1. Уточню проблему. Полный набор параметров выглядит примерно так:

```
static void Foo(string str1=null, string str2=null,[CallerMemberName] string methodname = null)
```

причем неатрибутированных параметров штуки 3, а то и 4. Поскольку они тоже дефолтные, то в итоге спиок вызова может включать от нуля до максимума параметров, и в этих условиях компилятор просто не соображает - то ли это str2, то ли methodname. Пока что это разрешается на уровне XML Comment'ов атрибутированных параметров - типа: "Don't change!", но кто их читает...

UPD2. @Alexander Petrov преложил обернуть атрибутированные параметры в классы. На самом деле эту возможность я обдумывал ранее, однако предположил, что в этой ситуации CallerMemberName будет обращаться к обертке. Но решил попробовать и, в принципе, получилось. Вызов сейчас выглядит примерно так:

```
Foo (new MemberName()); // или
Foo ("Bar", new MemberName())
```

Более того, для тех, кто не совсем в теме - таких аналогичных дефолтных атрибутов 4: CallerFilePath, CallerMemberName, int CallerLineNumber, и похожий на эти три string ParamName (префикс немного отличается).
Обертка позволяет все 4 атрибутированных параметров упрятать в один Context().
Таким образом, ошибка связанная с путаницей параметров исключается - сложно представить, что кто-то захочет в качестве Str2 передать класс Context.

Однако возникла другая проблема. Параметр Context context - обязательный, т.е. всегда указывается в вызове. А поскольку его основная цель отработать по умолчанию, его указание в вызове излишне и желательно его избежать, пока же вот так:

```
// определение
static void Foo(MemberName membername, string str1=null, string str2=null) 
=> Console.Writeline ($"{membername} {str1} {str2}");

// обертка
    public class MemberName
{
    public string ToString = null;
    public MemberName([CallerMemberName] string memberName = null) => ToString = memberName;
}

// вызов
Foo (new MemberName());
// или
Foo ("Bar", new MemberName());
```

Спасибо всем, особенно @Alexander Petrov. Окончательный вариант будет оформлен в виде ответа.

Comment: А ваш параметр обязательно должен быть помечен как `CallerMemberName`?

Comment: Сделать 2 метода: один публичный, второй internal

Comment: @Exploding Kitten, именно. И в этом суть проблемы.

Comment: @tym32167, ага, и в публичной перегрузке убрать параметры по умолчанию? Не сработает. Фишка в том, что параметры по умолчанию должны отработать и в публичной перегрузке тоже. И даже не так - именно в публичной перегрузке они должны отработать по умолчанию без возможности их изменения, в идеале - стать невидимыми.

Comment: Поставленную вами задачу решить невозможно.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, что ж, посмотрим. Но ваш ответ неполон. Обобщенно проблема выглядит, как корявое предоставление доступа к метаданным вызывающего метода. Это несомненно будет исправлено. Или уже исправлено, на что я рассчитываю. Так что, не невозможно, а невозможно сейчас.

Comment: @Владимир вот только нет никакого "доступа". CallerMemberName - это просто такая рекомендация, для CLR там просто метод и параметр. Параметр в метод можно передавать любой.

Comment: _то ли это str2, то ли methodname_ - тогда замените простые типы (string) на конкретные классы. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1220601/184217

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, рекомендация сделать что? А я отвечу. Если значение параметра дефолтное, тогда компилятор сам присвоит параметру имя вызывающего метода, а если не дефолтное, тогда да - передаст любой параметр. Но мне не надо любой, мне нужно имя вызывающего метода. И только. Поэтому параметр не должен быть проинициализирован вручную при вызове, но может по ошибке. Я эту ошибку хочу избежать.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, думал об этом, да не додумал. В любом случае - ваш ответ хорош, вне зависимости от того, сработает или нет.

Comment: Вы не сможете избежать вероятности ошибки используя `[CallerMemberName]`, пишите свой механизм, трассируйте стек вызовов.

Comment: @aepot, на самом деле уже смог, но возникла другая проблема. Возможно, только для меня, посмотрим. Текущее решение опишу в UPD. А ваше предложение вполне обосновано,но слишком громоздкое для столь простенькой вещи, как мне кажется.