# C#: конструктор копирования или конструктор-десериализатор из JSON

Tags: c#, сериализация

По условию задачи мне надо десериализовать объект из JSON:

1. Есть класс, в нём много свойств. Можно на первом этапе считать, что все свойства - «невложенные», то есть что-то вроде такого:

```
public class ContragentPayment 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
    public int? InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public decimal CurrencyRate { get; set; }
    public int? OrderId { get; set; }
    public string PaySubject { get; set; }
}
```

2. С сервера приходит сериализованный в JSON объект идентичной структуры (то есть, с теми же свойствами). При этом на клиенте я могу переписать класс как угодно, главное, чтобы тот же набор свойств можно было отобразить на клиенте.
3. Мне было бы очень удобно этот JSON передавать в конструктор, чтобы писать что-то вроде `ContragentPayment cp = new ContragentPayment(cp_as_json_string);`

Подключил пакет System.Text.Json, десериализую JSON так:

```
var tmp = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ContragentPayment>(cp_as_json_string);
```

Но я не могу понять, как поместить эту строку кода в конструктор, ведь `this`доступен только для чтения, то есть я не могу написать:

```
var tmp = new ContragentPayment(cp_as_json_string);
this = tmp;`
```

Вот если бы у меня в классе ContragentPayment был конструктор копирования, чтобы я мог инициализировать экземпляр объекта другим экземпляром объекта.

Я смотрю [пример](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor), и вижу, что в примере конструктора копирования используется перебор всех свойств вручную, мне же не хотелось бы этого делать, так как их достаточно много. То есть мне нужно либо что-то вроде `AutoMapper`, либо придётся «наступить на свою гордость» и написать блок кода, который сделает это через `Reflection`: переберёт свойства, но сделает это автоматически.

Однако, `AutoMapper` -- это лишняя внешняя зависимость, да и вообще -- стрельба из пушки по воробьям, а перебор через `Reflection` мне кажется вычурным и не соответствующим простоте задачи.

Возможно, я упускаю какую то очень простую вещь, на уровне базового синтаксиса языка, которая позволяет выкрутиться? Не посоветуете ли, в какую сторону копать?

Спасибо большое!

Comment: А какой смысл тут в конструкторе? Сами себе ведь делаете геморой, ибо что, будете в каждом классе дублировать код десериализации? Если так нужна простота, то сделайте метод расширения и используйте его как `var result = cp_as_json_string.FromJson<ContragentPayment>();` (или нечто аналогичное). Ну а так, посмотрите на реализацию того же синглтона, там обычно делают свойство/метод, который при первом обращение инициализирует класс, вот некий такой билдер и сделайте, но с десериализацией, получите тогда `var result = ContragentPayment.Build(cp_as_json_string);`.

Comment: S -- Single Responsibility Principle... Класс не должен заниматься сериализацией и десериализацией себя.

Comment: Вам не надо в конструктор, заведите статический метод и пишите `ContragentPayment cp = ContragentPayment.FromJson(cp_as_json_string);` Так кстати в самом дотнете многое сделано. Например `Color.FromArgb()` десереализует цвет из инта.

Comment: Вам приходит json с какого-то внешнего сервиса, на границе приложения вы один раз переводите его в объект  `ContragentPayment cp = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ContragentPayment>(cp_as_json_string)` и дальше везде работаете с объектом. Строка больше нигде не должна использоваться. Я не вижу даже смысла делать метод расширения: видна чётко одна зависимость, от сериализатора.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, чего именно Вы хотите добиться? Вам надо создать экземпляр типа из JSON, метод JsonSerializer.Deserialize уже делает это, не более и не менее, просто создаёт объект Вашего класса. Не могу понять, зачем Вам в конструкторе создавать второй экземпляр, а потом копировать из него свойства в первый, а тем более при чём здесь рефлексия (кстати, с ней дело не в вычурности, а в производительности). Просто присвойте результат метода Deserialize переменной и всё. Всё, что Вам надо сделано, не усложняйте жизнь себе, коллегам и сборщику мусора.

Comment: Большое спасибо всем за советы! Ну, бывает - бес попутал... Хорошо, с десериализацией - забили гвоздь в крышку! А насчет конструктора копирования без перечисления полей вручную - никакого простого совета нет? (мне кажется, это можно сделать через сериализацию - десериализацию)

Comment: По поводу копирования, реализуйте любым старым дедовским способом, что там внутри будет - не особо важно, если вас расход памяти и производительность устраивает. Хоть руками поля присваивайте, хоть через рефлексию ([фокусы-покусы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1215963/373567)), хоть через любой сериализатор (вспомнился `BinaryFormatter`, земля ему пухом).

Comment: Можно использовать `Object.MemberwiseClone`, делает `bit-by-bit copy` объекта, т.е. для полей значимых типов копирует по значению, для ссылочных - копирует ссылки.

Comment: Но идеологически правильнее будет реализовывать копирование через реализацию `ICloneable`.

Comment: @SmorcIRL идеологически очень часто классы, реализующие `ICloneable`, имеют конструктор, принимающий экземпляр своего типа. А внутри `Clone()` написано что-то типа `return new MyType((MyType)obj)`. То есть движок для клонирования может быть один и для конструктора, и для `Clone()`. Но реализация или нереализация интерфейса - дело хозяйское, я часто реализую, удобно и привычно, и так же часто через конструкторы. А потому что могу.

Comment: @aepot Просто как-то не очень имхо понятна обязанность конструктора принимающего объект этого же типа, в общем случае такой конструктор может применяться не только для копирования (пример - какие-нибудь односвязные списки c передачей предыдущего элемента). C `Clone()` же всё понятно по названию. Но офк правильно всё что не запрещает компилятор.

Comment: По поводу ICloneable. В Framework Design Guidelines рекомендуется не реализовывать его.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того, чтобы заполнить объект данными из JSON, можно использовать [`JsonConvert.PopulateObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PopulateObject.htm), если вы перейдёте на более старый Newtonsoft JSON.NET:

```
public ContragentPayment(string jsonSource)
{
    JsonConvert.PopulateObject(jsonSource, this);
}
```

Подобной функциональности пока [нету](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29538) в System.Text.Json, хотя существуют различные [обходные пути](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56835040/276994).

Но, как верно отмечено в комментариях, конструктор десериализации — это не самая лучшая идея: класс по идее не должен заниматься десериализацией самого себя.

Я бы посоветовал просто использовать `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ContragentPayment>(json)` вместо конструктора.

---

Для реализации копирования проще всего использовать `record`. В `record` и так объявлен клонирующий конструктор, но он объявлен как `protected`, и используется в конструкции `with`. Можно выставить это наружу:

```
public ContragentPayment CreateCopy() => this with { };
```

Внимание: при этом вы получите shallow copy, то есть, другой объект, у которого будут скопированы (но не склонированы!) все свойства. Впрочем, если ваши DTO-классы будут неизменяемыми (immutable), то разницы особой и нет.