# Как получить аттрибут свойства типа с помощью лямбда выражения?

Tags: c#, lambda, атрибуты, extension, expressions

Имеется расширениe для типа, которое используется для возврата атрибутов свойств:

```cs
public static T GetAttribute<T>(this Type type, string propertyName) where T : Attribute
{
    return type
        .GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        ?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false)
        .Cast<T>().FirstOrDefault();
}

var displayNameAttribute = typeof(Person)
    .GetAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>(nameof(Person.Id));
```

Недостаток в том, что имя свойства передаётся как текст и не связано с типом.
Можно ли каким-либо образом преобразовать это расширение для использования с лямбда выражением?
Хотелось бы использовать расширение таким образом:

```cs
var displayNameAttribute = typeof(Person)
    .GetAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>(p => p.Id);
```

На данный момент всё что я смог сделать (и то с помощью @AlexanderPetrov):

```cs
public static class TypeUtils
{
    public static TAttr GetAttribute<TAttr, TEntity>(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> argumentFunc)
        where TAttr : Attribute
    {
        string propertyName = GetMemberInfo(argumentFunc).Member.Name;

        return typeof(TEntity)
            .GetProperty(propertyName,
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            ?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttr), false)
            .Cast<TAttr>().FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private static MemberExpression GetMemberInfo(Expression method)
    {
        if (method is not LambdaExpression lambda)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(method));
        }

        MemberExpression memberExpr = null;

        if (lambda.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        {
            memberExpr = ((UnaryExpression)lambda.Body)
                         .Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        else if (lambda.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            memberExpr = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
        }

        return memberExpr
               ?? throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(method));
    }
}

// используется так
var attr = TypeUtils.GetAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute, Person>(p => p.Id);
```

Но у меня не получается сделать это именно как расширение для типа.

Comment: C полгода назад был хороший вопрос про построение fluent builder - типа вот как раз с дженериками и лямбдами и там помнится как раз такой пример был. (Сходу не нашёл, может позже допишу в комментариях) А может и заново проще будет ответить, чем дубликат искать.

Comment: @AK заранее премного благодарен! Сам долго искал, но ничего не нашёл :(

Comment: @AK https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1215963/373567

Comment: @aepot Точно, оно! Спасибо за ссылку. Пойду-ка я что ли конкурс заведу - и самому потом искать проще вопрос и пусть ещё повисит недельку, пособирает просмотры и плюсики.

Comment: Хорошее решение вы добавили в вопрос, или что-то с ним еще не так?

Comment: Вот, немного пошаманил над GetMemberInfo `private static MemberExpression GetMemberInfo(Expression method) => method is LambdaExpression lambda ? lambda.Body.NodeType switch { ExpressionType.Convert => ((UnaryExpression)lambda.Body).Operand as MemberExpression, ExpressionType.MemberAccess => lambda.Body as MemberExpression, _ => throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(method)) } : throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(method));`

Comment: @aepot внутренний перфекционист мучает меня вопросом: "Как реализовать это в виде расширения для типа? Тогда можно было бы использовать (как я писал в вопросе) `typeof(Person).GetAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>(p => p.Id)`.

Comment: Ну здесь надо выбрать, либо это обобщение, либо `Type`. Смешивать смысла ноль, вы уже сами знаете. Обобщение дает вам удобный синтаксис лямбды, только и всего.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static T GetAttribute<T, T2>(this Type type, Expression<Func<T2>> func)
    where T : Attribute
{
    var expressionBody = (MemberExpression)func.Body;
    string propertyName = expressionBody.Member.Name;

    return type
        .GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        ?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false)
        .Cast<T>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Использование:

```
var p = new Person();

var displayNameAttribute = typeof(Person)
    .GetAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute, int>(() => p.Id);

Console.WriteLine(displayNameAttribute.DisplayName);
```

Недостаток в том, что нужно явно указывать тип свойства в вызове метода. В данном случае указан `int`.

---

Можно объявить метод так:

```
public static T GetAttribute<T, T2, T3>(this Type type, Expression<Func<T2, T3>> func)
```

В этом случае становится не нужен экземпляр `var p = new Person();`.
Но дополнительно придётся указать тип в вызове метода:

```
var displayNameAttribute = typeof(Person)
    .GetAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute, Person, int>(p => p.Id);
```

Comment: Наверняка можно избавиться от явного указания типа, но что-то никак не соображу.